# Facing issues while automate ExtJS application with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, extjs

our application is fully developed with ExtJS and Jquery. i'm facing lot of issues in identifying the elements (xpath, css, etc) using Selenium webdriver. Also if we automate the UI interactions with Firefox, it is not working in other browsers.
How to resolve these kind of issues in Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best tool to automate ExtJS application? facing issues with Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688723/what-is-the-best-tool-to-automate-extjs-application-facing-issues-with-selenium)

Comment: yes, asking the same question in different way. For that question also, i didn't get any answer.